# Switching between min and max by user inter action

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have the following code which allows the user to choose between `min` and `max` filtering. However, `min` works on element `1` but `max` works on element `2`. Is there a better way to implement it?

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12'],
        ['C', '3', '88'], ['D', '4', '88']]
 
fn_max = False

if fn_max is True:
    mx = max(data, key=itemgetter(2))[2]
    mx_values = [d for d in data if d[2] == mx]
else:
    mx = min(data, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    mx_values = [d for d in data if d[1] == mx]   
    
print(mx_values)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You set a variable for each element that differs between the two branches.  Then replace the constants with the variables.  This is standard programming, no?

Comment: Note that `12 > 4` but `'12' < '4'` - your data consists of strings and not integers, but you appear to want to compare integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them into a function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12'],
        ['C', '3', '88'], ['D', '4', '88']]


def my_func(fn_max):
    func, i = (max, 2) if fn_max else (min, 1)
    mx = func(data, key=itemgetter(i))[i]
    return [d for d in data if d[i] == mx]


fn_max = False
print(my_func(fn_max))
```

Output:

```
[['A', '2', '4'], ['B', '2', '12']]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably better (although it's unclear what you need it for, so it's hard to say if it would really be better):

```
data = [
    ['A', 2, 4], 
    ['B', 2, 12],
    ['C', 3, 88], 
    ['D', 4, 88]
]

def fn_filter(fn, column, data):
    value = fn(rec[column] for rec in data)
    return list(filter(lambda rec: rec[column] == value, data))


print(fn_filter(min, 1, data))
print(fn_filter(max, 2, data))
```

Result:

```
[['A', 2, 4], ['B', 2, 12]]
[['C', 3, 88], ['D', 4, 88]]
```

`fn_filter` allows you to apply any function `fn` to a specific column `column` of the dataset `data` and will return a list of all the records in `data` that have that same value in that same column.